# Angular2 TynyMCE Editor de texto

Tags: angularjs, angular

Alguém consegue dizer se existe alguma propriede que no momento de clicar no editor de texto eu possa emitir algum evento.

Com o (ngModelChange) eu consigo digitar e fazer alguma ação, pórém eu preciso que no momento de clicar eu já possa emitir a ação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na configuração do módulo do Tinymce para o angular você pode forçar que o click do editor execute um click no container e através da API você pode definir o click do container como abaixo:

```
<app-tinymce [(ngModel)]="potato" (click)="doSomethingWithPotato()"></app-tinymce>
```

E no seu módulo você pode instanciar o Tinymce com a seguinte config para forçar o click no container:

```
TinymceModule.withConfig({
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('click', function(e) {
      editor.editorContainer.click();
    });
  }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar o evento padrao do html de blur ou focus

```
 <input (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()">
```

Comment: Estou chamando o componente <app-tynymce> o input text está dentro do componente, eu preciso de alguma propriedade que acesse o input interno

Comment: @Gustavo dentro do teu componente interno cria um método que pega o click do input e faz um EventEmitter para retornar para teu componente atual.

Answer (score 0):

É possível associar eventos ao seu component utilizando o `(onSelectionChange)="handleEvent($eventObj)"`, por exemplo.

É fortemente recomendável que você leia a [documentação do TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/#eventbinding)